# treeview bindeado en wpf desactivar nodos

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Tengo un treeview que esta bindeado a una clase:

El problema es que quiero agregar una propiedad que si tienen los treeviewitem, para activar o desactivar partes del tree, pero al bindear una clase propia, no se como agregar esa propiedad.

Probe:

- derivar mi clase de treeviewitem (no me anduvo el bind, ojo tal vez hice mal eso)
- agregar una propiedad enable (anda, pero no se que hacer con esa propiedad).
- transformar los items del arbol a treeviewitem (no anduvo, no son de ese tipo).

Entonces como hago para decirle al tree que determinados item estan desactivados (grisandolos, subrayandolos, no importa como, pero como para que el usuario no pueda hacer click sobre ellos).

Definicion del tree (xalm)

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView2" >
    <TreeView.DataContext>
        <Controles:ListaArbol/>
    </TreeView.DataContext>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type Controles:ListaArbol}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Image Source="{Binding Imagen}"  Stretch="Fill" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding texto}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Clase que se bindea:

```
public class ListaArbol: TreeViewItemBase
{
    public ListaArbol()
    {
        this.Children = new ObservableCollection<ListaArbol>();
    }

    public string texto { get; set; }

    public string Imagen { get; set; }

    public string Control { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ListaArbol> Children { get; set; }
}
```

La clase anterior deriva de:

```
public class TreeViewItemBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
.....
}
```

y para cargar el arbol hago algo asi:

```
List<ListaArbol> items = new List<ListaArbol>();
ListaArbol i1 = new ListaArbol { texto = "Archivos", Imagen = "Imagenes/blue-folder-vector.png", Control="ControlArchivos" };
ListaArbol i2 = new ListaArbol { texto = "Consultas", Imagen = "Imagenes/consultas.jpg", Control= "ControlConsultas" };

items.Add(i1);
items.Add(i2);
treeView2.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es añadir una propiedad a tu clase `ListaArbol` para marcar si es nodo está activado o no,por ejemplo `IsEnabled`:

```
...
public string texto { get; set; }
public string Imagen { get; set; }
public string Control { get; set; }
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
```

En tu XAML debes añadir un `Setter` "bindeado" a dicha propiedad dentro de `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView2" >
    <TreeView.DataContext>
        <Controles:ListaArbol/>
    </TreeView.DataContext>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type Controles:ListaArbol}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Imagen}"  Stretch="Fill" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding texto}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Por último, al inicializar los items de tu `ListaArbol`, pon esa propiedad a `true` o `false` si quieres activar o desactivarlo:

```
ListaArbol i1 = new ListaArbol { texto = "Archivos", Imagen = "Imagenes/blue-folder-vector.png",
                                Control = "ControlArchivos",IsEnabled=true };
ListaArbol i2 = new ListaArbol { texto = "Consultas", Imagen = "Imagenes/consultas.jpg", 
                                 Control = "ControlConsultas" ,IsEnabled=false};
```

En este ejemplo,el primer nodo estará activo y el segundo inactivo.